# 2 questions about zero point of function: $f(x) = x^2 \ln(x) - ax + 1$, with unknown parameter $a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

We know a function, $f(x) = x^2 \ln x - ax + 1$, with an unknown parameter $a \in \Bbb R$. There are two questions about this function:

(1) Find the range of $a$, if $f(x) \geq 0$ is always true.

(2) Define a function: $g(x) = f(x) - ax^3 + ax - 1 =x^2 \ln x - ax^3$. If we know that $g(x)$ has two **different** zero points $x_1, x_2$, prove that $x_1 x_2 > e^2$.

---

*The original question is shown above. And this one is questioned for students 16-17yrs old. They have learned basic calculus with integration and derivative. But without $\epsilon - \delta$ system.*

**For the first subquestion**, I know when $a=1$, the function $f(x)$ has only one zero point because its global lowest value is 0 when $x = 1$, then I found that the answer is $a \in (-\infty, 1]$. But I'm can get this answer **only with function graph**. Is there a logical way to prove it?

i.e. How to solve $f'(x) = 2x\ln x + x - a = 0$ analytically?

**For the second subquestion**, the only result I found is that $a \in (0,\frac{1}{e})$ for two different zero points. I tried:

$\ln(x_1) - ax_1 = 0, \ln(x_2) - ax_2 = 0\quad \Rightarrow \ln(x_1 x_2) - a(x_1 + x_2) = 0$

But I failed because the value of $x_1 + x_2$ is hard to handle.

Comment: Tip: use `\ln`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $f(x)\geqslant 0$ is equivalent to $a\leqslant \dfrac{x^2\ln(x)+1}{x}$. Let $h(x):=\dfrac{x^2\ln(x)+1}{x}$. Then, one has $h'(x)=\dfrac{x^2-1+x^2\ln(x)}{x^2}$ and $h''(x)=\dfrac{x^2+2}{x^3}\gt 0$. So, $h'(x)$ is increasing with $h'(1)=0$. Since the minimum value of $h(x)$ is $h(1)=1$, one can see that  $a\leqslant h(x)$ always holds if and only if $a\leqslant 1$.

---

(2) $g(x)=0$ is equivalent to $a=\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$. Let $j(x):=\dfrac{\ln x}{x}$. Then, $j'(x)=\dfrac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$. So, $j(x)$ is increasing for $0\lt x\lt e$ and is decreasing for $e\lt x$ with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}j(x)=-\infty, \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}j(x)=0,j(1)=0$ and $j(e)=\dfrac 1e$. Therefore, one has $0\lt a\lt\dfrac 1e,1\lt x_1$ and $1\lt x_2$. Since $a=\dfrac{\ln x_1}{x_1}=\dfrac{\ln x_2}{x_2}$, one finally gets $$x_1x_2=\dfrac{\ln(x_1)\ln(x_2)}{a^2}\gt e^2\ln(x_1)\ln(x_2)\gt e^2$$